# Force a string which sometimes can be a hyperlink to open a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, hyperlink

I have a textview in my app and the text gets updated regularly, the text can be a simple string or it can be a hyperlink. To recognise it's a hyperlink I've added `android:autoLink="web"` in my textview.

On clicking the textview a dialog fragment opens. The functionality is working fine with simple string but when it comes to hyper link automatically a browser opens. How do I force the hyperlink to just open the dialog fragment not the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's the way I do it:

```
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.my_string));
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.link)));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, START_INDEX, LENGTH, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        terms.setText(ss);
        terms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        terms.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

**UPDATE:**

Let us say your string is: "something LINK another thing" and you want only LINK part has underline and opens browser when you clicked on it. Then your `my_string` would be `something Link another thing`.

Then we create a `ClickableSpan` that you can make only some part of your text to be clickable....and then you set that with `setSpan`.....START_INDEX and LENGTH are the first index of your text that you want to be clickable, and the second one is the length of that clickable area.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what's happening here.

Comment: @Stackover67 I just update my answer.
Let me know if you had any questions.